# Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, the if statements and the conversions are not working

Tags: java, class, if-statement

I made this program to convert Fahrenheit with Celsius. I'm getting a compile error because it's bypassing the if statements and the conversions aren't doing anything.

```
     package temp;

        import java.util.Scanner;
```

> this is the class TheTemp

```
        public class TheTemp {
            private double tempValue;
            private char tempType;
            private static int obj;
```

> this constructor sets the default
>   0 degrees and Celsius

```
        public TheTemp(){
            tempValue = 0;
            obj = 0;
        }
```

> this next 3 constructors are for importing the values...
>   this one

```
        public void setTemp(double tempValue){
            this.tempValue=tempValue;
        }
```

> this one

```
        public void setTemp(char t){
            if(t == 'C'||t == 'c'){
                obj = 0;
                tempType = t;
            }
            if(t == 'F'||t == 'f'){
                obj = 1;
                tempType = t;
            }
            else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Choose ether C or F");
            }

        }
```

> and this one

```
        public void setTemp(char t, double tempValue){

            this.tempValue=tempValue;

            if(t == 'C'||t == 'c'){
                obj = 0;
                tempType = t;
            }
            if(t == 'F'||t == 'f'){
                obj = 1;
                tempType = t;
            }
            else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Choose ether C or F");
            }

        }
```

> this are the conversions
>   the first if statement is Celsius to Fahrenheit and
>   the second if statement is Fahrenheit to Celsius

```
        public void convertValue(){
            if(obj == 0){
                tempValue = 9*(tempValue/5) + 32;
            }
            if(obj == 1){
                tempValue = 5*(tempValue - 32) / 9;
            }
            else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Choose ether C or F");

            }
        }

        public double getTempValue(){
            return tempValue;
        }
```

> this is the program to test the class

```
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                TheTemp A = new TheTemp();
                Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
                double a;

                A.setTemp(55);
                A.convertValue();
                a=A.getTempValue();
                System.out.println(a);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: seriously folks, please stop downvoting this post. His way of documenting the class shows true effort.

Comment: What is `double tempType = 'c';` in the constructor supposed to do? --- The next 3 methods are setter methods, not constructors. --- Why is field `obj` static? It shouldn't be. --- What is the purpose of having both `tempType` and `obj`? You should just have a single `boolean`

Comment: @wero Showing true effort is not sufficient to make a good question. The OP mentioned getting compile errors, but failed to include the error text in the question, and didn't indicate which lines the errors were on. "I'm getting an error in my program" is not a good (or particularly clear) problem statement.

Comment: @Andreas i made obj only for the if statements and i made it static so all the methods could us it, and double tempType = 'c'; was a mistake i fixed that already

Comment: Where are you getting *compile* error? Please show error message. If you meant you're getting *runtime* error, please show stack trace, though I can show three places where that happens: The `if () {} if () {} else {}` statements are supposed to be `if () {} else if () {} else {}`. You're missing the `else` before the second `if`, in all three methods.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this code.. is weird in many ways.

Can you say what exactly the compile error is ?

But just as a start

```
 double tempType = 'c';
```

in your constructor makes no sense, 'c' is not a double. And you have defined tempType on top as a char, so if anything your constructor should look like this

```
    public TheTemp(){
        tempType = 'c';
        tempValue = 0;
        obj = 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry the compile error actually came from the "throw new IllegalArgumentException"  statement from the setTemp() methods or constructors in the if statmants

Comment: i really asking why the if statements and the conversions aren't working

Comment: tempType() is a char that's why i initialized it with 'c'

Comment: But you don't you make a new double tempType and never set the char tempType

And you never use the tempType char

Comment: ya true that was a mistake but i corrected it i think

Comment: how do you correctly set the char tempType, if you don't mind me asking

Comment: Like I said in my correction of your constructor, that one does set the char variable